# Creating a loop for javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I currently have the following javascript code that is repeated 20 times in my wordpress custom code section where custom javascript codes are inputted. I was wondering if there is a way to shorten them by using a loop?

**Example code 1**

```
var href1 = jQuery('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child(1) .item-property').html();
var link1 = "<a href='"+href1+"' target='_blank'>Join Now!</a>";
jQuery('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child(1) .item-property').replaceWith(link1);
```

**Example code 2**

```
var href2 = jQuery('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child(2) .item-property').html();
var link2 = "<a href='"+href2+"' target='_blank'>Join Now!</a>";
jQuery('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child(2) .item-property').replaceWith(link2);
```

As can be seen, there is a pattern to the code and I have relabelled them as Q.

```
var hrefQ = jQuery('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child(Q) .item-property').html();
var linkQ = "<a href='"+hrefQ+"' target='_blank'>Join Now!</a>";
jQuery('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child(Q) .item-property').replaceWith(linkQ);
```

So I was thinking of using a loop to generate variables and then use them in the above code?

```
var Q;

for (Q = 1; Q < 20; i++) {
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you try it out? are you having a problem?

Comment: You probably meant `for (var Q = 1; Q < 20; Q++)`

Comment: By the way, your variables are being taken as a literal string instead of a variable. It should be something like `jQuery('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child('+Q+') .item-property').replaceWith(linkQ);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could of course use a loop, but don't.

You've asked about a solution to your solution instead of to the initial problem, which seems to be to simply replace the content of each element with a link.

So instead, use the API designed for this purpose.

```js
jQuery('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li .item-property')
  .replaceWith(function() {
    return "<a href='" + this.innerHTML + "' target='_blank'>Join Now!</a>";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul class="grid-item">
    <li><span class="item-property">1</span></li>
    <li><span class="item-property">1</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-item">
    <li><span class="item-property">2</span></li>
    <li><span class="item-property">2</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-item">
    <li><span class="item-property">3</span></li>
    <li><span class="item-property">3</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-item">
    <li><span class="item-property">4</span></li>
    <li><span class="item-property">4</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-item">
    <li><span class="item-property">5</span></li>
    <li><span class="item-property">5</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-item">
    <li><span class="item-property">6</span></li>
    <li><span class="item-property">6</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You didn't show your HTML, but used `.html()` so I guess that's what you want, though it seems odd for an `href`. If all that's in each element is text, then use `this.textContent` instead.

---

And of course, you don't need jQuery for this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item:nth-child(5) li .item-property')
  .forEach(function(el) {
    var a = el.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("a"), el);
    a.href = el.innerHTML;
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.textContent = "Join Now!";
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  });
```

You can [patch `.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill) in browsers that don't yet support it.

---

However, if you *did* use a loop, you could make it simple with template literals, ***but don't do this*** since it's horribly inefficient. It's just for informational purposes.

```
// Inside your loop...
var hrefQ = jQuery(`.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child(${Q}) .item-property`).html();
var linkQ = `<a href='"${hrefQ}"' target='_blank'>Join Now!</a>`;
jQuery(`.grid-item:nth-child(5) li:nth-child(${Q}) .item-property`).replaceWith(linkQ);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. I am currently using your non-jquery solution. Could you please explain how to modify the code to patch  `.forEach()`? The code works fine on my desktop but not on my mobile phone (Chrome and Safari)

Comment: You're welcome. Check out this patch given in the [MDN documentation for NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill)